# How to add a video on a template with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, templates

I would like to watch my video inside the box of this template. Is it possible to make it with ffmpeg?

[image]

The size of the template does not matter. It can be larger than what's shown.

Comment: Providing the actual template image you will use, and providing the dimensions of your input video are needed to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: I apologize @LordNeckbeard. Here's the actual template i will use (1280x720)

http://i.stack.imgur.com/2alzT.jpg

and i would like my video to appear inside the box.The box size is    800x453

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
 ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i background_image.png -i mainmovie.mov -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[V1]; [1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=800:452[V2]; [V1][V2]overlay=shortest=1:x=240:y=134" out.mov
```

Here the background image ( eg `background_image.png`) is used as one input for the overlay filter, and the main movie (eg `mainmovie.mov`) is the other. To match the start time stamps I used the `setps` filter for both, setting the start time stamp to 0. The output of the second input is scaled to 800x452 **not** 800x453 because the scale filter has problems when the number is not divisible by 2.

The output of this is labeled [V2] and passed on to the overlay filter, while setting `shortest=1`, implying encode until the shortest input. Because the background image is generated in infinite loop, the shortest length here is the length of the input main movie. So it encodes till the end of the movie.

The positioning is at half the value of 1280-800=480, divide by 2 to get 240. Similarly for y pixel value. But your actual corner of the box may be different. And you may need to use more encoding parameters, depending on the input movie file and output required.